# Why does apache not work as expected (Order/Allow/Deny directives)?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have an apache 2 web server running here. In a directory on that server I have a `.htaccess` file:

```
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow From 192.168.1.0/24
  Allow From 10.0.0.0/24
```

I am on box 192.168.1.20. If I try to reach the directory I get a message about missing permissions on that direcory. If I just comment the second line (`#Deny from all`) I can reach the location.

As far as I understood I first define to evaluate the deny rules (deny all IPs) and then allow only the specified (here the two private subnets). This should result in a configuration where the location os reachable only from inside my private network.

Why do I get the missing permission error? Is there a possibility to show some more verbose log to search the error?

Comment: can you post the error? what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer shortly: I had a bad configuration in my DNS. Therefore I accessed through the external interface and all was correctly blocked.

Sorry for disturbing.